# Get directory name from file and check if they exist or not

Tags: bash, loops

I have a file with a list of folders in it. I have a script that will output if the folder exists or not by echoing TRUE and the folder name or FALSE and the folder name.

I want to be able to run this on each line of an external file so I can check if all the folders in the text file do or don't exist.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRECTORY="directory name"
if [ -d $DIRECTORY ]
then
    echo "TRUE  $DIRECTORY" >> folder_output.txt
else
    echo "FALSE $DIRECTORY" >> folder_output.txt
fi
```

The text file have is called folders.txt I need to loop every line in the folders.txt in to the variable `$DIRECTORY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file line by line.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line
do
    if [ -d "$line" ]
    then
        echo "TRUE $line" >> folder_output.txt
    else
        echo "FALSE $line" >> folder_output.txt
    fi

done < folders.txt
```